# Why in a finite dimensional space every orthonormal basis is basis

Tags: functional-analysis, orthonormal, schauder-basis, hamel-basis

Why in a finite dimensional space every orthonormal basis is basis

i know in infinite dimensional space every basis is orthonormal basis but converse is not true ( for example $l^2$ )  but in finite dimensional converse is true why **?**

Comment: Wait... what?  Look at your definitions.  An orthonormal basis is defined to be a basis which has the additional nice properties that the basis vectors are pairwise orthogonal as well as have norm equal to $1$.  The fact that an orthonormal basis is a basis is right there in the definition...

Comment: As for "*in infinite dimensional space every basis is orthonormal basis*" where did you hear that?  You can absolutely have a basis for an infinite space which is not orthonormal.  For $\ell^2$ for instance just use the usual norm and the basis $(4,0,0,\dots),(0,4,0,\dots),(0,0,4,\dots)$ and they won't be normal anymore, or use $(1,0,0,0,\dots),(1,1,0,0,\dots),(0,1,1,0,\dots),(0,0,1,1,\dots)$ etc and they won't be orthogonal anymore...

Comment: I believe that the OP is thinking about Hilbert bases.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that what you are talking about here are Hilbert bases.

In general, in a Hilbert space $H$, you can indeed have an orthonormal set $\{e_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ which is a Hilbert basis of $H$, but which is not a Hamel basis (that is, a basis in the Linear Algebra sense). Such a set is always linearly independent.

But if $\dim H<\infty$, then the set $\{e_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is finite too. And then, asserting that each $v\in H$ can be written as $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}a_\lambda e_\lambda$ just means that every $v\in H$ is a linear combination of elements of $\{e_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$. And therefore this set actually spans $H$.